# row keys through the hbase shell?

Tags: hbase

I am using

```
 scan 'table_name', { COLUMNS => 'column_family:column_qualifier', LIMIT => 2 }
```

to list 2 rows in a hbase table but I would like to know if it is possible to achieve following using hbase shell:

#### Questions

1. list all row keys through the hbase shell?
2. list only those rows, whose row keys have a particular word in it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A1. `hbase(main):015:0> count 'table_name', INTERVAL => 1`

A2. Use `RowKey` filter with `SubstringComparator`.

Usage :

```
hbase(main):003:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
hbase(main):005:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
hbase(main):006:0> scan 'test', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("word_by_which_you_want_to_search"))}
```

Comment: A1. Works perfect. Thank you! A2. got an error: NameError: uninitialized constant CompareFilter

Comment: have you imported it?"import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter"

Comment: sorry i didn't import first. This works like a charm. Thank you for your help. Is it possible to list only those rows that have a particular word in a column family and column qualifier?

Comment: scan 'test', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.QualifierFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("substring"))}

Comment: scan 'test', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FamilyFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("substring"))}

Comment: If you don't want to import: `scan 'test', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FamilyFilter.new(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator.new("substring"))}`

Comment: @Tariq: I need to further narrow the filter, suppose my column family name is element, qualifier is CountryCode and itz value is "US", so what will be the filter query

Comment: There's a performance concern for listing all the rowkeys - we can possibly print billions of row keys depending on what's in the table.

Answer (score 4):

KeyOnlyFilter - takes no arguments. Returns the key portion of each key-value pair.

Syntax: KeyOnlyFilter ()

Comment: Just to give an explicit example:  scan 'table1', {
 STARTROW=>"startrow",
 FILTER => "KeyOnlyFilter()",
 LIMIT => 10
}

Answer (score 2):

Earlier solution would be:

```
scan 'test', { 
  COLUMNS => ['col_family_name:col_name'], 
  FILTER => "RowFilter(=, 'substring:the_string_to_be_compared')" 
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit better? What do you mean by "earlier solution" also?

Comment: I'm going to assume that "easier" was meant (rather than "earlier").  That said, I'm struggling to find documentation on the possibly values given as the 2nd argument to RowFilter besides `substring:`...ah, [here's a bit of help](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_comparator).

Comment: does this method retrieve bringing 'rowkey'?