# Exception while doing hbase scan

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I was trying out [hbase spark distributed scan example](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/JavaHBaseDistributedScan.java).

My simple code looks like this:

```
public class DistributedHBaseScanToRddDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaSparkContext jsc = getJavaSparkContext("hbasetable1");
        Configuration hbaseConf = getHbaseConf(0, "", "");
        JavaHBaseContext javaHbaseContext = new JavaHBaseContext(jsc, hbaseConf);

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setCaching(100);

        JavaRDD<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>> javaRdd =
                  javaHbaseContext.hbaseRDD(TableName.valueOf("hbasetable1"), scan);

        List<String> results = javaRdd.map(new ScanConvertFunction()).collect();
        System.out.println("Result Size: " + results.size());
    }

    public static Configuration getHbaseConf(int pRimeout, String pQuorumIP, String pClientPort)
    {
        Configuration hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        hbaseConf.setInt("timeout", 120000); 
        hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "10.56.36.14"); 
        hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        return hbaseConf;
    }

    public static JavaSparkContext getJavaSparkContext(String pTableName)
    {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaHBaseBulkPut" + pTableName);
        sparkConf.setMaster("local");
        sparkConf.set("spark.testing.memory", "471859200");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        return jsc;
    }

    private static class ScanConvertFunction implements Function<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, String> {
        public String call(Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> v1) throws Exception {
            return Bytes.toString(v1._1().copyBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: /10.56.48.219:16020 is unable to read call parameter from client 10.56.49.148; java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GetRegionLoad
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.instantiateException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.makeIOExceptionOfException(ProtobufUtil.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRegionLoad(ProtobufUtil.java:1746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getRegionLoad(HBaseAdmin.java:2089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RegionSizeCalculator.init(RegionSizeCalculator.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RegionSizeCalculator.<init>(RegionSizeCalculator.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.oneInputSplitPerRegion(TableInputFormatBase.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.myproj.poc.sparkhbaseneo4j.DistributedHBaseScanToRddDemo.main(DistributedHBaseScanToRddDemo.java:32)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException): /10.56.48.219:16020 is unable to read call parameter from client 10.56.49.148; java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GetRegionLoad
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.readResponse(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.channelRead(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also tried bulk [get](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/JavaHBaseBulkGetExample.java) and [put](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/HBaseBulkPutExample.scala) examples and they are working correctly. So I was guessing whats going wrong with bulk scan example.

Comment: Based on my experience, it's because you are using hbase-spark connector, which is version 2.x but probably your HBase version is 1.x ? I got this functionality to work with the Cloudera version of the hbase-spark connector, which is 1.x

Comment: damn yess..my hbase is 1.x and hbase-spark connector is of 2.0. But I am using Apache HBase, can I use clourera (or even hortonworks) connector with apache hbase?

Comment: Yes, you can. I'll paste the link to it and the pom.xml in the answer, as probably no space here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Cloudera hbase-spark connector seems to work:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark?repo=cloudera

So, add something like this in pom.xml:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <name>cloudera</name>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

and for dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase-spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

One thing I noticed is that this functionality doesn't seem to reuse the HBase connection well and tries to re-establish it for every partition. See my question and related discussion here:

[HBase-Spark Connector: connection to HBase established for every scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494483/hbase-spark-connector-connection-to-hbase-established-for-every-scan)

For this reason I actually avoid this functionality, but curious to know your experience with this.

Comment: one last question, the [get](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/JavaHBaseBulkGetExample.java) example gets rows corresponding to the row keys specified. Is it possible to filter rows using substring of rowkey, if I want to fetch rows corresponding to rows keys containing certain string (which is [possible from shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16856483/1317018))?

Comment: I don't think so, because {get} is supposed to take an exact row-key. If you provide a partial key it won't match, and I'm not aware of any wild-card character for {get}. Beside, how would you provide a 'stop' character (i.e. instruct hbase where to stop). What you see done in the shell example that you provided is actually a {scan}, not a {get}. Scan allows you to provide a partial-key start and then a stop. I encourage you to use the scan

Comment: Now I am guessing how much code changes I will have to do with cloudera hbase-spark connector.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the mismatch of ***version*** of the  jars you have with respect to the hadoop and hbase and the code that you are running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).